# Is it possible to refer to a series of variables?

Tags: java, variables

I would like to refer to a variable whose name has a number in a System.out.print() method.

```
public class Loopname {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    int num = 1;
    String file1 = "Hello";
    System.out.print( "file" + num );
  }
}
```

When this code is run, I get "file1" as an output. This is completely understandable, but I would like to retrieve the value of it. I am doing this because I would like to call a series of these files without calling them individually in the print method.

Conceptual code:

```
 public class Loopname {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
     String file1 = "Hello";
     String file2 = "Hola";
     String file3 = "Bonjour";

     for (int i=1; i<=3;i++) {
       System.out.println( "file" + i );
     }
   }
 }
```

I would like the user to see:

```
Hello
Hola
Bonjour
```

I am open to any advice and simpler versions of code.

Comment: This is not the "way of Java", and so this won't work for the most part. As you gain more programming knowledge, you'll learn that variable names are not nearly as important as they seem to be, that they almost don't even exist in the running code.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you make your variables members of a class you could use reflection on that class to access them by name.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array:

```
String files[] = new String[]{"Hello", "Hola", "Bonjour"};

for (String file : files) {
     System.out.println(file);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this: String files[] = new String[]{"Hello", "Hola", "Bonjour"};   Using a 2 dimensional array? Something like: String files [][]= new String [][] {"Hello"}{"Bonjour"};

Comment: @user1299661: Well, you *could* use a 2D array. However, I am not really sure where you're going with this...

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that. You would need to put them into some kind of array and loop through them.

Comment: a) you actually *can* do that, b) you provide no reference for your claims, c) you provide no working solution to OP